# Cannot find django.views.generic . Where is generic. Looked in all folders for the file

Tags: python, django, generics

I know this is a strange question but I am lost on what to do. i cloned pinry... It is working and up . I am trying to find django.views.generic. I have searched the directory in my text editor, I have looked in django.views. But I cannot see generic (only a folder with the name "generic"). I cant understand where the generic file is . It is used in many imports and to extend classes but I cannot find the file to see the import functions. I have a good understanding of files and imports and i would say at this stage I am just above noob level. So is there something I am missing here. How come i cannot find this file? If i go to from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, I can easly find this but not 
 eg : from django.views.generic import CreateView

Where is generic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running this from a Python interpreter:

```
>>> import django.views.generic
>>> django.views.generic.__file__
```

This will show you the location of the `gerneric` as a string path. In my case the output is:

```
'/.../python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/__init__.py'
```

If you look at this `__init__.py` you will not see the code for any of the generic `*View` classes. However, these classes can still be imported from the path `django.views.generic` (if I am not mistaken, this is because the `*View` classes are part of the [`__all__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44843/3642398) list in `django/views/generic/__init__.py`). In the case of `CreateView`, it is actually in `django/views/generic/edit.py`, although it can be imported from `django.views.generic`, because of the way the `__init__.py` is set up.

This is technique is generally useful when you want to find the path to a `.py` file. Also useful: if you use it on its own in a script (`print(__file__)`), it will give you the path to the script itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot Elethan